# Too many redirects NSX Load Balancer (HA Proxy) Application rule

Tags: haproxy, f5-big-ip, nsx

We are trying to do a redirect from / to /access/signin however with the following application rule we see too many redirects (looping) for HTTPS, HTTP is working fine.

```
acl TEST-RDR hdr_dom(Host) -i www.test.com
acl TEST-RDR path_beg /access/signin
http-request redirect location https://www.test.com code 301 if TEST-RDR
```

Any advice or pointers would be really helpful, I am new to Application rules and trying to convert an F5 iRule (below)

```
when HTTP_REQUEST { 
  set host_info [string tolower [HTTP::host]] 
  set uri_info [string tolower [HTTP::uri]] 
    switch -glob $host_info { 
     "www.test.com" {
       switch -glob $uri_info { 
         "/access/signin*" {
          HTTP::respond 301 Location "https://www.test.com"
         }
         "/*" {
          HTTP::respond 301 Location "https://[HTTP::host][HTTP::uri]"
         }
       }
     }
     "*.test.com" { 
      switch -glob $uri_info { 
        "/access/signin*" {
          HTTP::redirect "https://[HTTP::host][HTTP::uri]"
        }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In haproxy declaring `acl` twice actually means `OR` of those conditions, so this:

```
acl TEST-RDR hdr_dom(Host) -i www.test.com
acl TEST-RDR path_beg /access/signin
```

means `Host = www.test.com` OR `path_beg /access/signin` which keeps evaluating to true, because you redirect to the same domain, so `https://www.test.com/` redirects to `https://www.test.com/` and you get redirection loop.

Instead try it this way:

```
acl host_www.test.com hdr_dom(host) -i www.test.com
acl url_access_signin path_beg /access/signin

http-request redirect location https://www.test.com/ code 301 if host_www.test.com url_access_signin
```

Haproxy has implicit `AND` when building conditions like in `http-request` above.
I don't know F5, so i can't say if that is exact translation.